# Convert JSON string to html text with bullet points in Angular

Tags: html, json, angular

I am using Angular for a project and I want to display some data on a page that comes from a JSON file. My problem is that the message is big and I would like it to be displayed with bullets points

```
"messageToDisplay": "this is a long message with 1) first bullet point 2) second bullet point",
```

Now in my html I would like this to be rendered in that way

```
<div>
<p>This is a long message</p>
<ul>
<li> first bullet point </li>
<li> second bullet point </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Is this even possible?
I am beginner in angular so I don't know everything

EDIT: More easily explained: can I add html tag inside a JSON string value?

Comment: Is the response type unified? i.e., does it always come in this format `...1)...2)...3)..`?

Comment: It does not come from anything I added the 1) 2) to make it more "explicit" for explaination. I could add something in the start like a dash or underscore if it makes it easier

Comment: I would not recommend placing html tags in json since json is a specific format for data exchange not for representation. I would suggest to think about changing your data structure on your server.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can place HTML into any JSON string value.

You can then display in angular using `innerHtml` binding.

```
<div [innerHtml]="response.message"></div>
```

The string gets sanitized for you by Angular so you don't have to worry about XSS.